# XML file opens in the browser but does not open with simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

When I open the URL of XML (client 2) on browser, it opens perfectly, but when I try to open the same URL (copied and pasted in full) with simplexml_load_file in PHP I got the errors, including 404 (NOT FOUND). Does anyone have any solution?

Note: I changed the customers's addresses (URL) and the path of the PHP file to '/path/arquivo.php'.

```
<?php

 $customers[1] = 'http://www.customer1.com.br/dados.xml';
 $customers[2] = 'http://www.customer2.com.br/dados.xml'; 

 $xml1 = simplexml_load_file ($customers[1]); // it works perfectly 
 $xml2 = simplexml_load_file ($customers[2]); // ERROR
```

Errors that I got

> Warning: file_get_contents (http://www.cliente2.com.br/dados.xml): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP / 1.1 404 Not Found in /path/arquivo.php on line 5
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file (): I / O warning: failed to load external entity "http://www.cliente2.com.br/dados.xml" in /path/arquivo.php on line 5

I've tried using `libxml_disable_entity_loader (false);` before opening the file but the error remains.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, with PHP 5.5.9.

I'll appreciate any help!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are these the actual error messages? ie: is the url given in the errors the actual url?

Comment: just to confirm, are you able to open both urls in a browser window but one of them gives out a 404 when you try to load it with `simplexml_load_file`? Can you access the url from a terminal via curl? ex. `$> curl http://problem.url.com/dados.xml` ?

Comment: Yes, both works. And Yes, I can access it from a terminal via curl.

Comment: I updated my question and ADDED a real example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the webserver filters out requests coming in without a proper `User-Agent`.

So you need to use `curl`, pass an user agent (I just used the latest Chrome user agent) and get the response.

```
<?php

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.cliente2.com.br/dados.xml');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36');
$response = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

//var_dump($response);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);

print_r($xml);
```

Be prepared for a long output

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works very well!